# What is the proper index to make SELECT queries more efficient?

Tags: sql

I have a table similar you can see below

```
Table Keywords
 Column ID
 Column Keyword
 Column Keyword2
```

the first query is

```
select keyword from keywords with (nolock) where keyword = keyword
```

another query for the same tabel is

```
select keyword2 from with (nolock) keywords where keyword2 Like 'keyword%'
```

1. My question is what index type to set on which columns int this table 
   to make a select process more sufficient? Is it should be clustered index or non-clustered? and on which columns I need to set it?

This table contains about **600k** rows and it constantly growing.

1. Another question I'm getting a dead-lock error when I trying to insert a new record to Keywords table. What can be the problem? I'm selecting records with nolock.

Thank you

Comment: The answer may be dependant on the DB. Is this SQL Server? `With (nolock)` makes me think it is

Answer (score 6):

Since your two queries are on totally separate columns, you will need two separate non-clustered indices:

- one index on `keyword` to speed up the first query
- a second index on `keyword2` to speed up the second query

And assuming you're using SQL Server: neither of them really makes a good clustered index, I would say - but a **good** clustered index would be really beneficial!

A good clustered index should be:

- unique
- small
- stable (never changing)
- ever-increasing

Your best bet would be on an `INT IDENTITY` field. See Kimberly Tripp's outstanding blog post [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) for more detailed background on the requirements for a good clustering key.

Answer (score 0):

If we are *really* seeing the only use cases, you want a clustered key on `keyword2` and then hope your DBMS is smart enough to optimize index use with `LIKE` operator. Clustering helps when the returned rows from a typical query are adjacent in the DB, so keeping the table in alphabetical order on `keyword2` will mean fewer pages have to be scanned on the SELECT. Clustering a table where access is pretty much random (e.g., user names) won't give you any more than a standard index.